# MongoDB : Show databases like MySQL

Tags: mongodb

My MongoDB has more than 100 databases in it.
Whenever i use show dbs command my screen is filled with all databases names and it makes hard to find a particular database.
How to display only those databases which contain a particular substring as we can query in MySQL for displaying particular databases with ( show databases like '%SUBSTR%' ) query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is:

```js
> db.getMongo().getDBNames().forEach(
    function(databaseName) {
      if (databaseName.match(/SUBSTR/i))
        print(databaseName);
    }
  );

> var showdbs = function(pattern) {
    db.getMongo().getDBNames().forEach(
      function(databaseName) {
        if (databaseName.match(new RegExp(pattern, 'i')))
          print(databaseName);
    });
  };

> showdbs('SUBSTR'); // ALL: showdbs();
```

Answer (score 2):

We do not have options like that. But your problem can be resolved by outputting the result into a txt file and later opening it

```
$ mongo | tee outnew.txt
```

In the mongo shell you can the give the show dbs command and exit.

```
mongo> show dbs;
mongo> exit
```

Then using gedit or excel access the outnew.txt file.
Hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a *nix OS you could run the following command.

```
mongo --eval "db.adminCommand('listDatabases')['databases']" | grep "SUBSTR"
```

Note: You need to be admin to run this command.